# Jquery Autocomplete not working after postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC 4, I have a textbox with Autocomplete functionality in a partial view And i am using this partial view in two views,view 1 and View 2.In View 1 ,it is working fine, as view 1 does not have any postback, while in View 2, i have a submit button causing postback,and after this postback,the partial is shown on the screen or else it is hidden.The Autocomplete here is not working.

```
$("#txtProduct").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    datatype: JSON,
                    url: 'UploadEligibilityCodes/GetAllMatchingProducts',
                    success: function (data) {

                        response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                            return {
                                label: value.ProductName.concat("(", value.ProductId, ")"),
                                value: value.ProductName,
                                pid: value.ProductId
                            };
                        }))
                    }

                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $('#hdnProductIdSearch').val(ui.item.pid);

            }
        });
```

This is the code of my text box defined in Partial view named SearchFilters.cshtml and View 2 which uses this partial view as follows.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm( "Validate","UploadEligibilityCodes",FormMethod.Post, new {id="UploadForm" , enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   {
 <div class="col-sm-1 form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="SIMPLDocumentUploadSave" id="importbtn" value="Import" style="width: 100px">&nbsp;Import</button>
                        </div>
}

 <div class="col-sm-12 form-group SIMPLAdvancedFilterOptions">
                               @Html.Partial("SearchFilters")
                        </div>
```

I saw some examples using Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager in ASP.Net, but the same i am not able to apply it html of mvc application.Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace your submit button with regular one and call `submit()` on form manually with jQuery? This can help you with postback issue

Comment: I have to upload a file on this submit button click.If i am replacing this with a button type, and writting an ajax to pass this file to the controller action,it is passing the file as null.Thats the reason i am keeping it as submit

Comment: so you should submit the whole form `$(form).submit()`

Comment: I am not able to understand this,could you pls elaborate.

Comment: if you call `submit()` method on jquery wrapper that wraps your whole form it will submit it to server with all form data. Lets assume you have your form with id `#myForm`. in jQuery you can do `$("#myForm").submit()` and this will submit your form with all its data inside. thats how you can manually submit form without `<button type="submit">`